# Getting JSON URL link from strings.xml to HTTP Request

Tags: android, json, string, url

I'm trying to translate my app which fetch JSON data from URL. My purpose is to add to get the URLs from strings.xml. This is a piece of code. When I'm trying with

```
String jsonURL = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.URL);
```

But the app is going forced closed.

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String jsonURL = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.URL);
    @SuppressLint("")

    private void fetchJSON(){
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
            protected String doInBackground(Void[] params) {
                String response="";
                HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<>();
                try {
                    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(jsonURL);
                    response = req.prepare(HttpRequest.Method.POST).withData(map).sendAndReadString();
            } 
        }.execute();
    }
```

strings.xml

```
<string name="URL">http://example.com/data.php</string>
```

onCreate() method

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fetchJSON();

    }
```

The logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.my.app, PID: 10378
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app/com.my.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:118)
        at com.my.app.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:42)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:43)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1243)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10378 SIG: 9
Process 10378 terminated.
```

Comment: Have you check the logs to see what is happening ?

Comment: @Bruno Please go through code. If you properly see in try catch code. Where getString required the Resource Integer. But he is passing string which is retrieved already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following Code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String jsonURL;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fetchJSON();
    }

    @SuppressLint("")
    private void fetchJSON(){
        jsonURL = getString(R.string.URL);
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
            protected String doInBackground(Void[] params) {
                String response="";
                HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<>();
                try {
                    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(jsonURL);
                    response = req.prepare(HttpRequest.Method.POST).withData(map).sendAndReadString();
            } 
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the log cat.

Comment: Done. Thanks for helping!

Comment: could you please share your whole onCreate() method.

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fetchJSON();

        });
    }

Comment: @Iliyan Please post in your question

Comment: @Iliyan please check updated code i posted properly

Comment: Finally. Thanks guys. You are awesome!